# Is there a way to automate the commit, push after applying a plugin in Jenkins 2 job?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I have been trying to automate the [code style formatting](https://github.com/coveooss/fmt-maven-plugin) in jenkins job, so in future when new code is added Jenkins takes care of code formatting (if not applied) - this would also help in legacy code repositories.

So the idea is to run the following stage before mvn install build,

```
stage('Apply Google code style ') {
      steps {
        script {
          sh "mvn com.coveo:fmt-maven-plugin:format"
        }
      }
    }
```

and if the build goes well, (Auto) commit these changes by identifying **if** any *.java files have changed.

I have been playing around with `changeset` and `changeLogSet` to identify the changes after applying the plugin, turns out these only hold the changes from the last commit.
Is there any way I can get the files changed in Jenkins after checkout?

Comment: why can't you use the native `git` command from the pipeline to do the commit for you?
follow `git add .`, `git commit -m "auto formatted committed from pipeline"`, `git push origin $branchName` . make sure git credential configure in the machine to do it.

Comment: true, although I meant to check only "IF" there are changes. but I get the point and found a solution. Will post it now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jenkins groovy function is the answer here, checking `git status --porcelain`

```
@NonCPS
Boolean getGitStatus() {
  def changedFiles = sh(returnStdout: true, script: "git status --porcelain")
  if(changedFiles != null) {
    return true
  } else {
    return false
  }
}
```

Checking this function in stage, and commiting if return true.

```
stage('Check for new changes and commit') {
  steps {
    script {
      if (env.BRANCH_NAME != 'hotfix/*') {
        def changedFiles = getGitStatus()
        if(changedFiles) {
          echo "Changes identified by Jenkins for Auto commit"
          sh "git add -u"
          sh "git commit -m 'Jenkins Auto Commit : Google code styler applied'"
          sh "git push origin $env.BRANCH_NAME"
        } else  {
          echo "No new changes identified"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```